# Best way to find string that sorts after all letters in the current culture

Tags: c#, sorting, culture

In C#, I am looking to have a list of names sorted alphabetically (case insensitive) in the current culture, and have a "fake name" that automatically sorts at the end of that list.

If the sort was using ASCII, we could use '{' as this is after 'z', so it'll always sort afterwards. However, this doesn't work in general for a culture based sort.

Right now I am using 'ZZZZZZZZZZZ' which works for English, but I know isn't the right answer - is there a good way of doing it?

(I'm aware that one option is to just put these to the end after sorting - unfortunately that isn't simple in this case)

```
        var strings = new[] {"abc", "zzz", "ZZZ", "{"};

        var sortedStrings = strings.OrderBy(x => x, StringComparer.Create(new CultureInfo("en-GB"), ignoreCase: true));

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", sortedStrings));
        // gives {,abc,zzz,ZZZ
```

Comment: Can you give an example where using `{` does not work?

Comment: Can you just give us some example input and output?

Comment: Edited to give example where { goes to the front of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i'm not wrong, the last character in utf-16 is `U+10FFFD` (`U+10FFFE` and `U+10FFFF` seems to be reserved)
So you may do this to get a string that I think would always be the last in a sort:

```
string fakeName= char.ConvertFromUtf32(0x10FFFD);
```

Comment: Assume you mean U+10FFFE and U+10FFFF are reserved - interesting, will try that.

Answer (score 2):

You could consider wrapping your name string in a type that can provide some metadata, for example:

```
public class SortableName
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsFakeName { get; set; }
}
```

You could expand upon this type and use LINQ to sort a collection based on your business logic, for example:

```
var names = new List<SortableName> { new SortableName { Name = "Test" }};
var sortedNames = names.OrderBy(n => n.IsFakeName)
                       .ThenBy(n => n.Name.ToLower()); //Case insensitivity
```

You can then project this into a collection of strings, preserving the order:

```
var justNames = sortedNames.Select(n => n.Name);
```